# Change img src attribute dynamically in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl

I have index.php:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.on').click(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "try.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'myVar': val}
                });
             });
            $('.off').click(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "try.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'myVar': val}
                });
            });
        });
    </script>  

<body>
    <img class="bulb"  src="bulb.png" alt="...">

    <button class="on" value="http://pageon.org">On</button>
    <button class="off" value="http://pageoff.org">Off</button>
</body>
```

I send value of buttons to try.php. Depending on the clicked button, I get one variable in the try.php file, for the ON button - 1 , for the OFF button - 0 (variable `$curl_response`). 
Is it possible to change the img in the index.php file dynamically, depending on the received variable from the try.php page? For example, if the received variable is 1, src = "bulb.png", and if 0, then src = "bulb2.png"?

try.php :

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['myVar'];
    $service_url = $name;
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);

    // Ustaw opcje połączenia
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
?>
```

EDIT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.btn').click(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "try.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'myVar': val}
success: function(result){
      switch(result){
         case "0":
           $(".bulb").attr("src", "bulb.png");
           break;
         case "1":
           $(".bulb").attr("src", "bulb2.png");
           break;          
      }
   }
      });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Of course.  Your PHP code would emit the value in the response and then your AJAX code would have `success` or `done` handlers to examine the response and perform actions on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `success` option that you pass to `$.ajax`. That's where you provide the callback function that you want to run if the https request status is 200. Something like

```
$.ajax({
    /** your other stuff, and... */
    success : function(data) {
        if (data == 1) {
            $('button.on').attr({src : "bulb.png"})
        }
        // and so on
    }
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use this, on the AJAX `success`:

```
$.ajax({
...
success: function(result){
      switch(result){
         case "1":
           $("#yourImage").attr("src", "yourImagePath1.jpg");
           break;
         case "2":
           $("#yourImage").attr("src", "yourSecondImagePath.jpg");
           break;          
      }
   }
});
```

**EDIT/SUGGESTION**

You don't need to trigger 2 separate events for each button if they are going to call the same URL and pass the same structure data. Use the same class to trigger:

**HTML**

```
<button class="buttonClass" value="http://pageon.org">On</button>
<button class="buttonClass" value="http://pageoff.org">Off</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(".buttonClass").click(function(){
     var val = $(this).text();

     //make here your ajax call passing 'val' 
});
```

Comment: It's good suggestion, thanks. I've corrected my code (look EDIT), 
but now nothing happens when I press the button, even the try.php file does not open.

Comment: Did you put your class `btn` in both buttons?

Comment: In your code is missing a `,` (comma) after the data structure, maybe this? I can't know.. Is the console showing any error's? Try putting a `alert(result)` on the success function....

Comment: Ok, it was missing a comma. I put alert and it works , but the photos doesn't change after pressing the button.

Comment: Are you sure that the `result` in the success is returnig correctly? (Put `alert()` on the `case` of the `switch`) Because the code to change the image `src` is really this `$("#image").attr("src","filepath.jpg");`

Comment: Alert on the case of the switch doesnt working, but I try return data on  console.log and it works, result is returning correctly, 0 or 1.

Comment: Is the Switch then, try use `1` instead of "1"

Comment: you might also try breaking it down into even smaller units. try running in your console the snippet that just changes an image element's src attribute to make sure that works. also examine the output sent from the server, as others have suggested. do some low-class debugging with, e.g.,  `console.log("something is happening")`

Answer (score 0):

Yes simply you can add if-else condition based on your flag received in your ajax success method and update img src attribute using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can send an AJAX request when one of the buttons is clicked and handle the response, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.on, .off').click(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "try.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'myVar': val},
success: function(result){
      switch(result){
         case "0":
           $(".bulb").attr("src", "bulb.png");
           break;
         case "1":
           $(".bulb").attr("src", "bulb2.png");
           break;          
      }
   }
      });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: unfortunately, nothing happens when I press the buttons

Comment: @Daro125 I have edited my answer. Can you check again? If you take a look at the network tab of your browser's dev tools, do you see a request being sent? Are there any errors?

Comment: In your code after "data: {'myVar': val}" must be comma. But it still doesn't working. I checked network tab and request is sending. Everything looks OK, but the picture doesn't change

Comment: @Daro125 sorry, I have pasted your edited code and changed that, did not observe you missed a comma there... What is the answer you get in the Network tab?

Comment: The answer is 0 or 1. I used @David code and it works, I don't know why switch doesn't works

Comment: @Daro125 switch cases check for exact equality. "1" == 1 but "1" !== 1